# How to send a big file on gmail without using google drive?

Tags: email, gmail, email-attachments, gmail-api, gmail-imap

My employer doesn't allow to download anything from google drive.
In that case How can I send a big file on gmail without using google drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could host on another file sharing website. Then provide the link inside the email. You could use OneDrive and share the file.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Trust me I have been looking for a solution for almost a month. My employer doesn't even allow dropbox. OneDrive is working perfectly though

Comment: Yeah I have an private Cloud server and I love it. OneDrive was great for sharing non-essential files too.